# Is it safe to use an LG charger on a Moto X?

Tags: battery, charging

I have a 2014 Moto X, and a Nexus 4. Is it safe to charge my Moto X using my Nexus 4 charger?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, no problem. They both use a regular micro USB format.